# AngularJS UI.Bootstrap Alert text not displaying and dismiss button not responding

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a Bootstrap alert by following the [example](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert) in the documentation. This is my HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div ng-init="alerts=[{type: 'danger', msg: 'Test'}, {type: 'success', msg: 'Another'}]">
    <alert close='closeAlert($index)' ng-repeat='alert in alerts' type='alert.type'></alert>
```

And this is the result:
[image: Red bar and green bar without text]

The text is not showing and clicking on x does not remove the alert. I'm not seeing any Javascript errors. I'm able to use other ui.bootstrap components such as the date picker and modal.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.13 and ui.bootstrap 0.10.0.

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text is not showing as the content of the `<alert></alert>` element is empty in the code you've provided. I guess you wanted to write:

```
<alert close='closeAlert($index)' ng-repeat='alert in alerts' type='alert.type'>
    {{alert.msg}}
</alert>
```

Then, for the close "not working" I suspect some scoping issue, but to confirm we would need to see implementation of the `closeAlert` function. Where / how did you define it?